# Selecting the right children of a class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="movies">
  <div class="movie" id="226260" movie-id="226260">
    <div class="movie-header">
      <h4 class="">Boyhood</h4>
      <div class="movie-trailer-tools movie-tools">
        <a class="add-trailer" data-toggle="modal" href="">
          <img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_b_table_add">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-visibility">
          <img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_eye">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-link"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.movies').on("click", '.toggle-visibility',function(event){
      eyeImg = $(this).closest('.movie').children('.toggle-visibility').children('img');
      var toRem = eyeImg.hasClass('ic_eye') ? 'ic_eye' : 'ic_eye_grey';
      var toAdd = eyeImg.hasClass('ic_eye') ? 'ic_eye_grey' : 'ic_eye';
      eyeImg.removeClass(toRem).addClass(toAdd);
    });
</script>
```

I want to change the class "icon ic_eye" to "icon ic_eye_grey" and vice-versa from the class "toggle-visibility" when the user clicks the image, but my jquery code isn't doing it right. Can anyone help me to get the correct value of the variable eyeImg?

By the way, there could be multiple div class="movie" because displaying the movies is inside a loop.

Comment: Use `find` instead of `children` to get descendants elements too (not only children).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` you are looking for is the child of the clicked `toggle-visibility` element, so you can use `.find()` in the context of `this` to find it. Then you can use toggleClass() to toggle the class

```js
$('.movies').on("click", '.toggle-visibility', function(event) {
  $(this).find('img').toggleClass('ic_eye_grey ic_eye');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.ic_eye {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ic_eye_grey {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movies">
  <div class="movie" id="226260" movie-id="226260">
    <div class="movie-header">
      <h4 class="">Boyhood</h4>
      <div class="movie-trailer-tools movie-tools">
        <a class="add-trailer" data-toggle="modal" href="">
          <img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_b_table_add" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-visibility">
          <img src="//placehold.it/16" class="icon ic_eye" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-link"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working.. What I want is that, when the image is clicked, it would automatically toggle the class. How can I do that?

Comment: @user3815765 there is a syntax error... missing `)` at the end

Comment: @user3815765 also need to prevent the default action of the anchor click... also inspect the element to see whether the class is getting changed

Comment: It's working fine now. Thank you so much! I was stuck since last week :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change:

```
eyeImg = $(this).closest('.movie').children('.toggle-visibility').children('img');
var toRem = eyeImg.hasClass('ic_eye') ? 'ic_eye' : 'ic_eye_grey';
var toAdd = eyeImg.hasClass('ic_eye') ? 'ic_eye_grey' : 'ic_eye';
eyeImg.removeClass(toRem).addClass(toAdd);
```

To:

```
var eyeImg = $(this).children('img');
eyeImg.toggleClass('ic_eye ic_eye_grey');
```